# Relative links not working after goBack was called

Tags: android, html, hyperlink, android-webview

I created a simple app to reproduce the issue. I have an html file with relative links (with `#` sign). I'm loading the file into Android's `WebView`. But I can go by link only once. After returning back nothing happens when I click on a link.

Steps to reproduce:

- Open the page
- Click on the Link 2
- Press Back button on the device
- Click on the link 2 - **nothing happens**

Here are the sources:

faq.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densityDpi=medium-dpi">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>FAQ</h1>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#Foo">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Bar">Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>

        <h1><a name="Foo">Link 1 body</a></h1>

        <p>a very very very long text</p>

        <h1><a name="Bar">Link 2 body</a></h1>

    </body>
</html>
```

activity_webview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/outer_background">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

FaqActivity.kt

```
class FaqActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var webView: WebView

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    override fun onCreate(args: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(args)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview)
        if (supportActionBar != null) {
            supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
            supportActionBar!!.setTitle(R.string.preference_about_faq)
        }
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)

        val sb = StringBuilder()
        try {
            val inp = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.faq)
            parseStream(inp, sb)
        } catch (e: Resources.NotFoundException) {
        }

        webView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        webView.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                // removes white screen blinking in the night mode
                webView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
                return if (url.startsWith("http")) {
                    val uri = Uri.parse(url)
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
                    try {
                        startActivity(intent)
                    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {

                    }
                    true
                } else {
                    false
                }
            }
        }
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, sb.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", null)
    }

    private fun parseStream(inputStream: InputStream, builder: StringBuilder) {
        val NL = System.getProperty("line.separator")
        val scanner = Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8")
        try {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                builder.append(scanner.nextLine() + NL)
            }
        } finally {
            scanner.close()
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            android.R.id.home -> {
                super.onBackPressed()
                return true
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

The source is a Kotlin file, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't affect the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `webView.pageUp(true)` in `onBackPressed()` function, instead of `webView.goBack()` In this way when you click the back button on the device, it scrolls to the top.

Comment: that doesn't solve the issue. relative link can be in the middle of the page.

Comment: Ok than,  you define `scrollY` next, assign `scrolledY = webView.scrollY` in `onPageFinished()` method. And finally, use `webView.scrollY = scrolledY` instead of `webView.goBack()`. I tried, it works.

Comment: Ok. If we'll use Stack to store Y coordinates (in case we have several link transitions), it works. But can we fix the cause of the issue and do not try to fix the consequences?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the adapted and tested code from [ugurcmk answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57221682/1219012).
I hope it will help someone.

```
class FaqActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var webView: WebView
    private val navigationStack = Stack<Int>()

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    override fun onCreate(args: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(args)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview)
        if (supportActionBar != null) {
            supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
            supportActionBar!!.setTitle(R.string.preference_about_faq)
        }
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)

        val sb = StringBuilder()
        try {
            val inp = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.faq)
            parseStream(inp, sb)
        } catch (e: Resources.NotFoundException) {
        }

        webView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        webView.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                navigationStack.push(webView.scrollY)
                // removes white screen blinking in the night mode
                webView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
                return if (url.startsWith("http")) {
                    val uri = Uri.parse(url)
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
                    try {
                        startActivity(intent)
                    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                    }
                    true
                } else {
                    false
                }
            }
        }
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, sb.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", null)
    }

    private fun parseStream(inputStream: InputStream, builder: StringBuilder) {
        val NL = System.getProperty("line.separator")
        val scanner = Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8")
        try {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                builder.append(scanner.nextLine() + NL)
            }
        } finally {
            scanner.close()
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        // the first element stores the first non-link onPageFinished, ignore it
        if (navigationStack.size > 1) {
            webView.scrollY = navigationStack.pop()
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            android.R.id.home -> {
                super.onBackPressed()
                return true
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```